# Padding with single space in Python string format()

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, formatting

I'm afraid this is a basic Python issue, but I couldn't find a proper answer to this.
I want to add a single padding space in front of a placeholder.

This is my example:

```
user = 'Jhon'
'Hi {u}!'.format(u=user if user else '')

# result
'Hi Jhon!'
```

Now everything is fine until my `user` var is empty or false, in that case this is the result of above

```
'Hi !'
#  ^ notice the empty space
```

Instead I want `'Hi!'` as a result.

Now I've tried with `format()` padding options like `{:>1}` but ofc is not working since it will add enough padding to reach a character length of 1.

I ended up doing something like this:

```
'Hi{u:>{p}}!'.format(u=user if user else '', p=1+len(user))
```

The above works fine, but I think it's kinda hackish and I'd like to now if there is a inbuilt way of doing this that I'm missing.

Thank you!

Comment: Avoid the issue: `'Hi {u}!'.format(u=user) if user else 'Hi!'` – easy to read and flexible.

Comment: How about `'Hi{u}!'.format(u=' ' + user if user else '')` ?

Comment: Both of you are right indeed, @Ryan suggestion looks quick and clear but unfortunately in my situation I can't use it (the example string was a reduced and simplified case to show my problem).

Comment: If @PM2Ring publish his suggestion as an answer I'll mark it as solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the solution I posted in the comments:

```
'Hi{u}!'.format(u=' ' + user if user else '')
```

The solution you posted in the question doesn't quite work, but it can be fixed by changing your padding length calculation to

```
p=bool(user) + len(user)
```

The `bool` function determines whether it's argument is True-ish or False-ish and returns `True` or `False`, respectively. But `True` and `False` can be used in arithmetic operations where they evaluate to 1 and 0, respectively.

Here's some code that demonstrates various solutions, including a couple that use literal string interpolation aka f-strings, which are available in Python 3.6+.

```
for user in ('John', ''):
    print('user is {!r}'.format(user)) 
    # Gruber
    print('Hi{u:>{p}}!'.format(u=user if user else '', p=1+len(user)))
    # Gruber, fixed
    print('Hi{u:>{p}}!'.format(u=user if user else '', p=bool(user) + len(user)))
    # Ryan
    print('Hi {u}!'.format(u=user) if user else 'Hi!')
    # PM 2Ring
    print('Hi{u}!'.format(u=' ' + user if user else ''))
    print('Hi{p}{u}!'.format(u=user, p=' ' if user else ''))
    # Python 3.6
    print(f'Hi{user and " " or ""}{user}!')
    print(f'Hi{" " if user else ""}{user}!')
    # Old `%-style` interpolation
    print('Hi%s%s!' % (user and " " or "", user))

    print()
```

**output**

```
user is 'John'
Hi John!
Hi John!
Hi John!
Hi John!
Hi John!
Hi John!
Hi John!
Hi John!

user is ''
Hi !
Hi!
Hi!
Hi!
Hi!
Hi!
Hi!
Hi!
```

For info about f-strings please see [Formatted string literals](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#f-strings) in the official Python docs. Also see [PEP 498 -- Literal String Interpolation](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0498/) and [PEP 536 -- Final Grammar for Literal String Interpolation](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0536).

Comment: Thank you for the very detailed explanation and that nice looking `f-string` didn't know about it! For anyone interested look [this](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.6.html#whatsnew36-pep498) and [this](https://cito.github.io/blog/f-strings/)

Comment: @Gruber f-strings are awesome. I generally don't use them in my SO answers since not everyone has 3.6 installed (I installed the alpha version last May). But I guess I should add some links to my answer.